# How to define callbacks like simultaneous setting ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my application containing companies and projects, these models are defined like this.

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170927135313) do

  create_table "companies", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "high_price_company_id_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["high_price_company_id_id"], name: "index_companies_on_high_price_company_id_id"
  end

  create_table "projects", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "price"
    t.integer "company_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["company_id"], name: "index_projects_on_company_id"
  end

end
```

`high_price_company_id_id` is foreign key and indicate high price company record. I call `save` twice. But, It is a little bit wasteful, isn't it? How to define efficient call backs. I want to call `save` only once.

```
2.3.3 :001 > company = Company.new
 => #<Company id: nil, name: nil, high_price_company_id_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
2.3.3 :002 > 4.times {company.projects.new(price: rand(1..100))}
 => 4 
2.3.3 :003 > company.save
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "companies" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", "2017-09-27 15:12:54.852223"], ["updated_at", "2017-09-27 15:12:54.852223"]]
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "projects" ("price", "company_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["price", 34], ["company_id", 1], ["created_at", "2017-09-27 15:12:54.856119"], ["updated_at", "2017-09-27 15:12:54.856119"]]
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "projects" ("price", "company_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["price", 77], ["company_id", 1], ["created_at", "2017-09-27 15:12:54.859440"], ["updated_at", "2017-09-27 15:12:54.859440"]]
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "projects" ("price", "company_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["price", 50], ["company_id", 1], ["created_at", "2017-09-27 15:12:54.862167"], ["updated_at", "2017-09-27 15:12:54.862167"]]
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "projects" ("price", "company_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["price", 91], ["company_id", 1], ["created_at", "2017-09-27 15:12:54.863989"], ["updated_at", "2017-09-27 15:12:54.863989"]]
   (2.8ms)  commit transaction
 => true 
2.3.3 :004 > max_price_proj = company.projects.maximum(:price)
   (0.4ms)  SELECT MAX("projects"."price") FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."company_id" = ?  [["company_id", 1]]
 => 91 
2.3.3 :005 > company.high_price_company_id_id = max_price_proj
 => 91 
2.3.3 :006 > company.save
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (2.2ms)  UPDATE "companies" SET "high_price_company_id_id" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "companies"."id" = ?  [["high_price_company_id_id", 91], ["updated_at", "2017-09-27 15:13:30.411374"], ["id", 1]]
   (2.7ms)  commit transaction
 => true
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the name of your FK `high_price_company_id_id` is misleading. An option is to rename it to `highest_priced_project_id`.

To update that FK you can define a callback in Company:

```
before_save do
  self.highest_priced_project_id = self.projects.max_by(&:price).id
end
```